# Google Cloud: Simple web app/UI for database content maintenance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-apps, powerapps

I am looking for a simple UI solution to add/edit/delete values in a Google SQL database.

Why:
We are using Google Big Query and Google SQL databases. For the ETL process some mapping parameters are configured in Google Sheets and then accessed in the ETL (e.g. if you get "BLN" in a certain column, replace it by "Berlin").

Using Google Sheets is error prone and I actually would like to store the mapping tables in a Google SQL database. The content of the mapping tables are filled/adapted by non-developers, also. I therefore would like to provide a simple online App/UI (preferable in the Google Cloud Platform universe) where users can just edit the content of defined tables in a grid.

What I tried:
- While there are online solutions available, they do not seem to use/access Google SQL databases and/or use their own user administration (and monthly costs per user).
- Google provides "Google Apps", which may be used to create a suitable online app, but only as part of the GSuite
- AppSheets was bought by Google Cloud, but does not seem to be integrated in GCP, yet
- Microsoft PowerApps might also by suitable to create a suitable online app, but would require additional user account management in MS universe, a gateway to the DB and - in general - would be a cross-cloud solution.

Is there anybody with a similar requirement and experiences, how this could be achieved?

Thank you!

HerrB92

Comment: quick question, is it a must for you to use google sql database or you can be open to use Azure sql database? If you use Azure sql database you are already in Ms env and using PowerApps should not be an issue?
Also it should not be a problem unless there is an connector available to connect with Google sql database for PowerApps

Comment: Changing the environment may be one possibility. Currently I would have liked to use  a database within Google Cloud, as ETL & orchestration which have to access the data are located there. If also the "Database WebApp" would be located there, then I could use the existing Google cloud accounts for access control.

Comment: I believe that what you need is **phpMyAdmin**, a free and open source administration tool for MySQL. [This is a tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine) of using it on App Engine with Cloud SQL. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only relevant google connectors available is the [google sheets connector.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/googlesheet/), which you want to move away from anyway.

The connector defines the available api transactions you can make to the sheet in either a canvas power app, or a power automate process. The user will need an [appropriate Microsoft license to run the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/pricing-billing-skus), as well as the access with a google account to the spreadsheet.

[There aren't any existing connectors to google cloud sources](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Can-Power-Apps-write-back-to-Cloud-SQL-google/td-p/340819), but you can create one yourself using the [google cloud api](https://cloud.google.com/apis/), and the c[ustom connector instructions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank)

If you are only looking for a place to store data that works well with power apps, check out the [common data service (CDS).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/data-platform-intro)

Comment: Thank you. I should be able to provide a connector so that I can connect a MS PowerApp with a MySQ/PostgreSQL within the Google cloud. Do you know of any other alternative to create or use a "Database WebApp" within the Google cloud universe?

Comment: @HerrB92, I don't have any bright ideas. I am not super familiar with Google's cloud DB offerings. Looking at this though: https://cloud.google.com/products/databases/. My guess is that if you are doing ETL operations then traditional SQL is what you are looking for, but depending on what tools you are using to do this (python script vs sql vs 3rd party software) and what the end use case is, you may want to explore NoSQL like Bigtable or Firestore. In my experience API endpoints are easier in custom connectors than SQL queries, but still doable.